# Django / Python : Change uploaded filename before saving file

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I am creating a site where users can upload images. I need to make sure that each filename has a unique name to prevent the files from overwriting each other. I will generate the unique name. But how do I change the filename before saving the file?  I see that there are ways to change the folder that it is saved to, but that's not quite what I'm after.

```
class saved_photos(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20) 
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/things/', blank=True, null=True)
```

In my code I do:

```
new_name = get_unique_name()
p = saved_photos(name = new_name, photo = request.FILES)
p.save()
```

What I need is for the actual name of the saved file to be new_name.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define [`upload_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) function.

Comment: Doesn't that just change the file location, not the filename? I want all my files to be saved in the same folder.

Comment: Can you give a code example, because I'm not seeing how. Is there a name attribute that I can change??

Comment: @user984003 the function generates a path which will be appended to your `MEDIA_ROOT`. If it return the string `blablabla.jpg`, every file will be saved in `MEDIA_ROOT` as `blablabla.jpg`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. In my model I added the field "photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_path_and_name)". Then in models.py I also defined a function: def get_path_and_name(instance, filename): new_name = 'blabla.jpg' return new_name

Comment: And also, Clippit is right, duplicate file name are renamed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Django can handle the unique filename correctly. The duplicate file name will be renamed automatically.
If you want to set the filename manually, just define `upload_to` function as DrTyrsa said. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673647/enforce-unique-upload-file-names-using-django/2677474#2677474) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

An example of **custom upload_to** function which set file name based on instance attributes

```
import posixpath
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class UploadToWithTpl:
    """Set Django file name based on instance attributes """
    def __init__(self, upload_to_tpl):
        self.upload_to_tpl = upload_to_tpl

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        if not filename:
            return

        new_name = replace_special_unicode_to_ascii(filename).strip()
        if remove_substrings(new_name, ' ', *string.punctuation) == '':
            new_name = 'file'

        upload_to = self.upload_to_tpl.format(self=instance)
        return posixpath.join(upload_to, new_name)
```

**Usage**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    hash = UniqueAutoGeneratedField()
    json_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to=UploadToWithTpl('protected/json_files', 'data_{self.hash}.json'))
```