# How to use django-filebrowser rename a file before uploading it to a folder

Tags: django, upload, django-filebrowser

like django's upload_to

```
def upload_to(instance, filename):
    filename = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    ym = time.strftime('%Y%m')
    return 'uploads/%s/%s.jpg' % (ym,filename)

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    photo = models.ImageField(u"Image (Upload)",upload_to=upload_to)
```

file saved 'uploads/%s/%s.jpg'

but change for

```
photo = FileBrowseField("Image", max_length=200, directory="uploads/", extensions=[".jpg"], blank=True, null=True)
```

How to rename a file before uploading it to a folder
like django's upload_to

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enforce unique upload file names using django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673647/enforce-unique-upload-file-names-using-django)

Answer (score 1):

In filebrowser/sites.py you can create a hook for this when uploading / handling uploads:

```
def _upload_file(self, request):
    """
    Upload file to the server.
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        folder = request.GET.get('folder', '')

        if len(request.FILES) == 0:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request! No files included.')
        if len(request.FILES) > 1:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest('Invalid request! Multiple files included.')

        filedata = list(request.FILES.values())[0]

        fb_uploadurl_re = re.compile(r'^.*(%s)' % reverse("filebrowser:fb_upload", current_app=self.name))
        folder = fb_uploadurl_re.sub('', folder)

        path = os.path.join(self.directory, folder)
        # we convert the filename before uploading in order
        # to check for existing files/folders
        file_name = convert_filename(filedata.name)
        filedata.name = file_name
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name
        ....
```

You can modify file_path here to whatever you like, or modify the file name.

For those of you that just want to ensure that files are not overwritten, you can set the FILEBROWSER_OVERWRITE_EXISTING flag in your settings.py as such:

```
FILEBROWSER_OVERWRITE_EXISTING = False
```

This will ensure that when you edit your files you give them a unique name, and it also ensures new uploads get their filename converted to something unique using filebrowsers convert_filename method defined in filebrowser/utils.py

More on filebrowser settings [here](http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#main-url-paths-settings). Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For all these many years of this question and similar questions on other sites, I have not found a ready-made solution, but only hints of it. It's time to post the solution:
`signals.py`:

```py
from filebrowser.signals import filebrowser_pre_upload
import os
import time

def pre_upload_callback(sender, **kwargs):
    fullname = kwargs['file'].name
    filename, extension = os.path.splitext(fullname)
    new_filename = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')

    kwargs['file'].name = new_filename + extension


filebrowser_pre_upload.connect(pre_upload_callback)
```

I hope I helped someone