# Access renamed image name from ModelForm in views?

Tags: python, django, modelform

Is there any option to get new filename uploaded by ModelForm in views.py?

I have ModelForm like this. I want to rename all files uploaded by users to unique name and followed this guide  [Enforce unique upload file names using django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673647/enforce-unique-upload-file-names-using-django)

models.py

```
class SomePhotos(models.Model):

    def get_file_path(instance, filename):
        ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        return os.path.join('some_photos/', filename)

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = get_file_path)
    link = models.URLField(verbose_name = u'URI', null = True, blank = True)
    title_color = RGBColorField()
```

This works great - files are saved as unique name to right directory, but my function in vievs.py stopped working because before unique renaming I have been using filename from POST but now file has other, unique name!

views.py

```
filename = request.FILES['image'].name
```

forms.py

```
class MotivatorForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
        model = SomePhotos
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you saved your `ModelForm`, you can get at the file's path using your instance's `.image.path`

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MotivatorForm(request.POST, request.FILE)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            filepath = instance.image.path
    # etc...
```