# How to set ImageField default name to be the pk (unique ID) of the model instance?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 1 image per model object instance and I think a reliable way to name each one would be to use the ID of the object. How can I set the ImageField of my model to use the ID of the object?

Answer (score 0):

An `ImageField`'s [upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) parameter is what is used by Django to determine uploaded files' path. It can be passed a callable,  called with the model instance and original filename as parameters. That allows custom and instance specific behaviours.

However, using the ID in the filename is not a good idea because, as stated in the documentation, when `upload_to` is called, the model instance has, in most cases, not yet been saved to the database. It means that on object creation, the object does not have an ID yet.

A solution could be to always same model instances first and only then set their `ImageField` but does two saves to the database and requires extra work from you. I advise you to find another unique way to name your images. Have a look at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673647/enforce-unique-upload-file-names-using-django) for example.