# How to use django.core.files.storage.get_available_name?

Tags: django, django-models

I am storing files and need a unique file name. I found [a suggestion to use django.core.files.storage.get_available_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676847/214742) but I am completely missing something. I tried this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name         = models.CharField( max_length=200, null=True ) 
    filecontent  = models.FileField( null=True, upload_to=Storage.get_available_name(name) )
```

And got the error: `TypeError: unbound method get_available_name() must be called with Storage instance as first argument (got CharField instance instead)` which I interpret as meaning that I am trying to run the method on the class but that I need a storage-instance to run it on. There exist something called DefaultStorage which is supposed to be [something that "provides lazy access to the current default storage system"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.DefaultStorage) but that one does not have the `get_available_name` method  but only a method `_setup` which can't be called on the class either. So how am I supposed to get an instance to work on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `upload_to` argument is for directory path that you want to upload your files to. The argument for storage is named just `storage`

So what you should do if you want to change default Django's Storage  implementation is to use for example

```
    filecontent = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='path/to/dir', storage=FileSystemStorage())
```

---

If you need to implement your own way to play with filenames you just have to create class that inherits from `Storage` and to overwrite it's `get_available_name` method. For example:

```
    class MyOwnStorage(FileSystemStorage):
        def get_available_name(self, name):
            if self.exists(name):
                #return something
            else:
                #return something_else
```

and then use it as follows:

```
    filecontent = models.FileField(null=True, upload_to='path/to/dir', storage=MyOwnStorage())
```