# give unique names for images uplodaded via imagefield django

Tags: django, forms, image

I have a form with an imagefield in it and i want to give the images unique names to avoid overwriting how can i acheive that ?

**models.py**

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Payment_ID = models.ImageField(upload_to='pay_proof/')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="X")
    Review_result = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Not yet reviewed")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s'% self.Status

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Status
```

Comment: Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673647/enforce-unique-upload-file-names-using-django/2677474#2677474)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `save` method and give whatever name you want to give your Image file.

```
def uniqueimage(name):
    image_name = "Logic to uniquely name the image"
    return image_name

class Payment(models.Model):
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Payment_ID = models.ImageField(upload_to='pay_proof/')
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=5, default="X")
    Review_result = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="Not yet reviewed")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kargs):
        if self.Payment_ID:
            self.Payment_ID.name = uniqueimage(str(self.Payment_ID.name))
        super(Payment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**NOTE:** Remember, this will not work when you directly update a field with `.update` method.